# No '+=' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've been updating my Swift code for Swift 3 (really excited) and so far so good. 
But I did tumble accros one little bit of code I can't seem to update.

I KNOW I am missing something very simple, but I just can't see what.

Here is what I have in Swift 2.2:

```
var column = 0

[...]

for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {
    [...]

    column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
}
```

The `++column` is of course being deprecated in Swift 3 in favor of `column += 1`

However, in THIS context, it produces an error:

> No '+=' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Int'

Since this line of code (`column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column += 1`) produces an error, I tried the following:

```
var newCol = column
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : newCol += 1
```

But I get the same error.

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`+=` does not return a value. You need to break this out. Luckily in your case that's straightforward and clearer than the original:

```
column = (column + 1) % numberOfColumns
```

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column + 1
```

Comment: It answers the OP's question most clearly and directly but as usual Rob Napier's answer is the elegant Swifty way. :)

Comment: yeah, what can ya do?

Comment: I tried this out, but it just adds 1 instead of += 1. `.map { _ in NSIndexPath(forRow: insertPos++, inSection: 0) }` In my case, the `n + 1` doesn't work