# No '+" candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject' Error in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this function that animates a UIImageView:

```
override func deselectAnimation(_ icon : UIImageView, textLabel : UILabel, defaultTextColor : UIColor) {
    playMoveIconAnimation(icon, values:[icon.center.y + 4.0, icon.center.y])
    playDeselectLabelAnimation(textLabel)
    textLabel.textColor = defaultTextColor

    if let iconImage = icon.image {
        let renderImage = iconImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        icon.image = renderImage
        icon.tintColor = defaultTextColor
    }
}

func playMoveIconAnimation(_ icon : UIImageView, values: [AnyObject]) {

    let yPositionAnimation = createAnimation("position.y", values:values, duration:duration / 2)

    icon.layer.add(yPositionAnimation, forKey: "yPositionAnimation")
}
```

After I upgraded to Swift 3 I started receiving the following error:

```
No '+" candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject'
```

I read in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696321/no-candidates-produce-the-expected-result) that the function should have return values but I don't know how to implement this. I would appreciate your help resolving this error

Comment: post the signature of function *playMoveIconAnimation*.

Comment: Hi @xhamr, 
func playMoveIconAnimation(_ icon : UIImageView, values: [AnyObject]) {

        let yPositionAnimation = createAnimation("position.y", values:values, duration:duration / 2)

        icon.layer.add(yPositionAnimation, forKey: "yPositionAnimation")
    }

Comment: Try like this `CGFloat(icon.center.y + 4.0)`

Comment: change it to`func playMoveIconAnimation(_ icon : UIImageView, values: [Any]) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting just values typed as `CGFloat` change it by:

```
func playMoveIconAnimation(_ icon : UIImageView, values: [CGFloat]) {

    let yPositionAnimation = createAnimation("position.y", values:values, duration:duration / 2)

    icon.layer.add(yPositionAnimation, forKey: "yPositionAnimation")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nirav D and Leo Dabus I was able to fix it, I don't have an explanation but this is the code that worked at the end:

```
override func deselectAnimation(_ icon : UIImageView, textLabel : UILabel, defaultTextColor : UIColor) {
    playMoveIconAnimation(icon, values: [CGFloat(icon.center.y + 4.0)])
    playDeselectLabelAnimation(textLabel)
    textLabel.textColor = defaultTextColor

    if let iconImage = icon.image {
        let renderImage = iconImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        icon.image = renderImage
        icon.tintColor = defaultTextColor
    }
}

func playMoveIconAnimation(_ icon : UIImageView, values: [Any]) {

    let yPositionAnimation = createAnimation("position.y", values:values as [AnyObject], duration:duration / 2)

    icon.layer.add(yPositionAnimation, forKey: "yPositionAnimation")
}
```